# How many different casts are possible if $6$ actors apply for $3$ unfilled male roles in a play given that Tom is selected and Joe is not?

Tags: permutations, combinations

**Questions** There are 3 unfilled male roles in a play, 6 actors including Tom and Joe are auditioning for the
roles, how many different casts including Tom but not Joe?

I thought that since Tom is in and not Joe, the correct equation would be to just do $C_4^2$ since there is 2 spots left with 4 people available. However, it's saying that the answer is 36. Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 2):

Tom has one of the three roles, and Joe does not, leaving 4 others to vie for 2 remaining roles, so there are ${4 \choose 2}=6$ different ways to complete the set of three persons that get a role.

Assuming the roles are different, there are $3!=6$ ways to assign the $3$ roles to those $3$ people, so that gives a total of $6*6=36$ different casts.

Answer (score 1):

Tom can select his rôle in $3$ ways. The second rôle can then be casted in four ways, since Tom is out, and the third rôle in three ways. This gives $3\cdot 4\cdot 3=36$ possible castings.